# Is there a way to remove something locked to the launcher using terminal?

Tags: 16.04, launcher, show-desktop

I have Show Desktop locked on my launcher, and I can't appear to unlock it. Nothing happens when I right-click it unlike with other applications. Is there a way to unlock it from the launcher for example by using the CLI. Is there a simple way to do this? Also, presumably this is some sort of a bug so is there a way to report this? I've only had Ubuntu for a few days :x

My version: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution isn't really intuitive. In both your 16.04 version and 14.04 click on the `Settings` icon in Launcher. Then select `Appearance`. Then pick `Behavior` tab. This screen will appear:

[Settings Appearance Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQFlI.png)

mark the check box beside `Add show desktop icon to the launcher`

Took me a year to stumble across it myself :)